# Connect to amazon AWS RDS

Tags: php, pdo, localhost, rds

I'm able to connect to amazon rds from mysql workbench, but with the same credentials in a php script (with pdo) I can't.
The security group has inbound rules that allow my IP (myIp/32)

I have an **access denied for user user@myIp**.

This how I handle my connection:

```
$dsn = Config::get('db.type') . ':host=' . Config::get('db.host') . ';
port=' . Config::get('db.port') . ';
dbname=' . Config::get('db.name') . ';
charset='. Config::get('db.charset'); 
$this->bdCon = PdoConnector::getInstance($dsn, Config::get('db.user'), Config::get('db.password'));
```

Comment: Pls, add some code or reference.

Comment: this how I handle my connection:

$dsn = Config::get('db.type') . ':host=' . Config::get('db.host') .
               ';port=' . Config::get('db.port') .
               ';dbname=' . Config::get('db.name') .
               ';charset='. Config::get('db.charset');

$this->bdCon = PdoConnector::getInstance($dsn, Config::get('db.user'), Config::get('db.password'));